# I am Curious on how should I approach to get the JSON to Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write code to use data to generate a report. Instead of iterating through the dictionary, I wanted to use Pandas this time.

So, the first issue I faced was null in the data. I corrected it using `json.loads()`.

I am trying to understand how can I get the nested JSON to Pandas.

How should I go about getting the below data to pandas? `read_json()` throws an error.

```
{
    "Scans": [
        {
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Id": "5a8f415a-5146-4e39-8827-33cdb14ad478",
                    "Host": "xyz.com"
                }
            ],
            "Id": "51b13233-b3de-4f26-81d6-0001314f635f",
            "Status": 32,
            "StartTime": "2021-05-25T16:00:13.16",
            "WindowScanStart": "2021-05-25T16:00:00.76",
            "WindowScanStop": null,
            "StartedBy": "8cafa5bc-b0df-496f-bab7-74f71eeadf9d",
            "StoppedTime": null,
            "CompletionTime": "2021-05-25T17:18:43.007",
            "IsApproveRequired": false,
            "IsMonitoring": false,
            "IsUploaded": false,
            "IsImported": true,
            "SubStatus": null
        },
        {
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Id": "6108c410-7d5c-41c9-979a-c8bf70e6f6bf",
                    "Host": "abc.com"
                }
            ],
            "Id": "de3a98a3-cb95-42ce-874b-00037347ebba",
            "Status": 72,
            "StartTime": "2021-06-07T19:50:01.85",
            "WindowScanStart": "2021-06-07T19:49:44.517",
            "WindowScanStop": null,
            "StartedBy": "b6a3f887-0b4a-43e1-ba5b-fd93e60e58b6",
            "StoppedTime": null,
            "CompletionTime": "2021-06-07T19:50:53.667",
            "IsApproveRequired": false,
            "IsMonitoring": false,
            "IsUploaded": false,
            "IsImported": false,
            "SubStatus": null
        },
        ],
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Reason": null,
    "ErrorMessage": null
}
```

I am able to handle nulls using `json.loads()`. How can I create a Pandas Dataframe from this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is the comma after the } in the line before the ],

There is no following element, so the comma is not correct.

Remove that and try again.

```
{
    "Scans": [
        {
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Id": "5a8f415a-5146-4e39-8827-33cdb14ad478",
                    "Host": "xyz.com"
                }
            ],
            "Id": "51b13233-b3de-4f26-81d6-0001314f635f",
            "Status": 32,
            "StartTime": "2021-05-25T16:00:13.16",
            "WindowScanStart": "2021-05-25T16:00:00.76",
            "WindowScanStop": null,
            "StartedBy": "8cafa5bc-b0df-496f-bab7-74f71eeadf9d",
            "StoppedTime": null,
            "CompletionTime": "2021-05-25T17:18:43.007",
            "IsApproveRequired": false,
            "IsMonitoring": false,
            "IsUploaded": false,
            "IsImported": true,
            "SubStatus": null
        },
        {
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Id": "6108c410-7d5c-41c9-979a-c8bf70e6f6bf",
                    "Host": "abc.com"
                }
            ],
            "Id": "de3a98a3-cb95-42ce-874b-00037347ebba",
            "Status": 72,
            "StartTime": "2021-06-07T19:50:01.85",
            "WindowScanStart": "2021-06-07T19:49:44.517",
            "WindowScanStop": null,
            "StartedBy": "b6a3f887-0b4a-43e1-ba5b-fd93e60e58b6",
            "StoppedTime": null,
            "CompletionTime": "2021-06-07T19:50:53.667",
            "IsApproveRequired": false,
            "IsMonitoring": false,
            "IsUploaded": false,
            "IsImported": false,
            "SubStatus": null
        }
    ],
    "IsSuccess": true,
    "Reason": null,
    "ErrorMessage": null
}
```